# Is there an efficiency difference between calling a library and operating directly?

Tags: performance, go, math

Not sure if I worded it properly, but the gist is:

Is it more efficient to call `math.Pow(x, 2)` or should I just use `x*x`?

I've tried them both, but, unfortunately, I can not detect the microsecond differences that may exist in my test file.

Comment: For just squaring a value.  If `x` is an integer, then `math.Pow` takes you into floating point space with all the potential inaccuracies it's known for on other platform.  Overflow issues aside, `x*x` will surely be faster and exact.  If you're doing something inherently floating point centric (e.g. raising pi to the power of e), then the library function makes more sense.

Comment: @selbie Thank you, I didn't realize the additional context would help.  Your answer makes perfect sense.  I was calculating the magnitude of a vector, so I think I'll stick with the library.

Comment: `*so I think I'll stick with the library*` - That's the opposite of what I was trying to suggest for a `square` operation.  `x*x` is hard to beat for int or float values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually function calls take some additional time (for example, to pass params and return it to/from function). But for simple cases Go can make some optimisations like inlining.
As described in the document [CompilerOptimizations](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CompilerOptimizations) there are several conditions:

> Only short and simple functions are inlined. To be inlined a function must conform to the rules:
>
> - function should be simple enough, the number of AST nodes must less than the budget (80);
> - function doesn't contain complex things like closures, defer, recover, select, etc;
> - function isn't prefixed by go:noinline;
>   function isn't prefixed by go:uintptrescapes,
> - since the escape information will be lost during inlining;
> - function has body;
>   etc.
> - gc: 1.0+
> - gccgo: -O1 and above.

Answer (score 0):

It's faster to simply use `x * x` than to call the function. This is because your processor can directly process your data. If you're calling the function, it takes more steps to process that instruction.

Comment: While this is almost certainly true, _why_? Because if Go has decent JITing, there is no difference, it will have replaced `Math.pow(int,int)` with just `int * int` prior to execution. So do you have any links that show Go doesn't JIT optimize this?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I don't understand this comment. IIUC Go complies to machine code, not an intermediary bytecode used in JIT compiler systems? Are you talking about compiler inlining optimizations?

Comment: That just makes it even more important to explain why it would be faster, because if Go compiles to native code, then the odds of the two statements being the same thing once things actually run are even higher.